# Define an API that accepts multiple types each of which has its own range of possible values

Tags: c, api, struct

I want to define an API that accepts a (type, value) pair and performs some operation on them.

```
typedef enum {
    TTL_ENTRY = 1,
    ACCESS_ENTRY = 2
}type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t type;        
    uint32 value;    
}type_val_t;

int entries_add(size_t count, type_val_t *type_val);
```

Each type has it's own range of possible values.

TTL_ENTRY's value can be a uint32 with any value.

ACCESS_ENTRY's value should accept only values from the enum:

```
typedef enum {
    STATE_NONE = 0,        
    STATE_DROP,            
    STATE_PATH             
    /* ... */
}state_t;
```

Is there a way to make this API more clear about which value should pair with which type?
Or somehow bind a value type for each type from type_t?

I thought converting value type from a uint32 into a union of possible values, like so:

```
typedef union {
    uint32 ttl_bitmap;
    state_t state;
}value_t;


typedef struct {
    type_t type;        
    value_t value;    
}type_val_t;
```

But even when using this kind of type it is not 100% clear which value should be coupled with which type.

Answer (score 1):

I think based on your limited example that using a `union` for `value_t` is probably a good idea.

About the best you can do beyond that, in C, is to name the fields in the union directly after the enums which select those fields so the correspondence is clear to any user of these data structures.

For your example this might mean you should make `value_t` look more like this:

```
typedef union {
    uint32 ttl_entry;
    state_t access_entry;
} value_t;
```

So when choosing your type selector enum identifiers you might consider how they could also be used as field names.

You may then also want to write a macro or set of macros for accessing each field based on the enum value.

There may be other ways to design your API and data structures in a more C-friendly way, but you would have to describe your larger problem (probably in another question) to get more guidance.